# Can you have general communication between an attiny84 and arduino without making attiny unreprogrammable

Tags: arduino, attiny

I have an arduino uno.   I have 4x attiny84.  now I want communication - general communication using usi and spi
protocol in a certain program between the arduino uno and attiny such that uno will be the  thing between  the tiny avr and my computer.  therefore I want to know if there is a way to do what I mentioned. I also want to know if the pins(those which are used for programming) are automatically initialized to their correct functions at a reset.

Comment: That depends on what you want to communicate add what effort you want to put. You should bit bang a i2c, use an existing i2c implementation and if you want to go hardcore you can make up your own 1 or 2 wire based communication protocol.

Comment: IO IO its off to work I go. History repeats itself. What distance? EMI sources? Impedance ought to be reduced to increase SNR at faster rates.